# Pandas groupby(), then add missing rows

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have some measurement for each city each year:

```
   City   Year    Income
1  NYC    2000    1.1
2  NYC    2001    2.4
3  NYC    2002    3.4
...
12 London 2000    1.2
13 London 2001    1.5
...
```

`pd.groupby('City')`

```
   City   Year    Income
   NYC    2000    1.1
          2001    2.4
          2002    3.4
   London 2000    1.2
          2001    1.5
   Pairs  2000    3.2
          2001    1.31
          2002    2.2
```

Now I know the Year for each city should be [2000,2001,2002].
How can I add missing rows? Here, London doesn't have 2002. So I want to achieve:

```
   City   Year    Income
   NYC    2000    1.1
          2001    2.4
          2002    3.4
   London 2000    1.2
          2001    1.5
          2002    NA
   Pairs  2000    3.2
          2001    1.31
          2002    2.2
```

Comment: Hi Zachary, can you post your current code?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033038/9357244

Comment: Hi! The solution in the link works!
df.Year = pd.Categorical(df.Year) 
df.groupby(['City','Year']).sum()

This will add rows for missing years. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `df.groupby(['City','Year']).sum().unstack('Year').stack('Year', dropna=False)`.

Comment: How do we mention the range by this unstack and stack?  For example, if I wish to have to records from 1998 to 2010 in the asked question above. How do we mention the size or range of year records?

Answer (score 0):

As commented: stack, unstack:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"city":["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
     "income":[1,2,2,3, 4,3,2,1],
     "year": [2000,2000,2001,2001, 2000,2001,2002,2000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#I want to calculate mean income per city and year
df.groupby(["city", "year"])["income"].mean()
# city  year
# A     2000    1.5
#       2001    2.5
# B     2000    2.5
#       2001    3.0
#       2002    2.0

#city A doesnt have any incomes for year 2002 in the original data so that year is missing in the groupby result.

df.groupby(["city", "year"])["income"].mean().unstack(fill_value=0) #Unstack to pivot, and fill missing values with 0
# year  2000  2001  2002
# city                  
# A      1.5   2.5   0.0
# B      2.5   3.0   2.0

#Then stack 
df.groupby(["city", "year"])["income"].mean().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
# city  year
# A     2000    1.5
#       2001    2.5
#       2002    0.0
# B     2000    2.5
#       2001    3.0
#       2002    2.0
```